# How do I make authenticated calls to Google Cloud Endpoints from an iOS client using Google Sign-in for iOS?

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-signin

I've implemented these instructions in my iOS app:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in

And these ones in my Google Cloud Endpoints API:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_ios

except that of course I don't do the bit with the `GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch`.

The two do not marry up. The endpoints service in the iOS app needs an authorizer set on it, one that implements `GTMFetcherAuthorizationProtocol`. Where do I get this authorizer from the Google Sign-in callbacks?

This callback on the AppDelegate gets passed a GIDGoogleUser instance, which has a GIDAuthentication instance, which has an accessToken field (String). That's what I want to pass to App Engine:

```
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!) {
    log.debug("Access token: \(user.authentication.accessToken)")
    // TODO: What do I do with this now?
}
```

Here's where the generated service needs the token. In my case the API is not very well named as just "Api", so the generated sources are GTLServiceApi, GTLQueryApi, etc.

```
private func executeQuery(query: GTLQueryApi, completionBlock: (object: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void) -> Void {
    let service = GTLServiceApi()
    service.retryEnabled = true

    // Whatever we set here should implement GTMFetcherAuthorizationProtocol. Where do we get one of those from the Google Sign-in SDK?
    // service.authorizer = TODO

    service.executeQuery(query, completionHandler: {(ticket, object, error) -> Void in
        completionBlock(object: object, error: error)
    })
}
```

Comment: I think sharing more of your code would be helpful here

Comment: The Sign-in code is no different to what's in your docs linked above, but I've added my Cloud Endpoints client code.

Comment: It seems as though the Endpoints client library has its own means of auth which is described in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_ios?hl=en), and this may or may not overlap with the Identity Toolkit sign-in flow. I'm not sure if it's possible, though, and this will take some research on your end to determine. Possibly you can manually-instantiate the API service object using credentials (presumably the auth token) which you got from the Sign-in flow?

Comment: This was possible with the Google+ Sign in. Did the Identity Toolkit team at Google not talk to the App Engine team before they built this?

Comment: In the [docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in) you linked for the Identity Toolkit Sign-In flow, you can find a link to a doc describing [how to send the ID token received by your callback handler (``) to a back-end server](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/backend-auth) (ie. your endpoints module) and use it for verification of the user.

Comment: [The Endpoints docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_ios?hl=en) describe a sign-in flow which requests scopes your Endpoints API specifies, not just the basic user profile info requested by the Identity Toolkit Sign-In flow.

Comment: Hi, I tried passing `self.service.authorizer = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser.authentication.fetcherAuthorizer()` but that didn't make any difference. Can you please tell where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I've been tracking this issue for months, and finally figured it out...)

Once you are signed in, the `GIDGoogleUser` object returned has the authorizer attached as:
`user.authentication.fetcherAuthorizer`

This object can be used as the authorizer for the endpoints service and everything seems to work!

That said, if you want to make your app more closely follow the approach laid out at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_ios, you might instead use [GTMAppAuth](https://github.com/google/GTMAppAuth), which seems to be the more similarly designed replacement for the GTMOAuth2 approach in that example.

Comment: I haven't checked this, but I'll take your word for it!

Comment: Hi, I tried passing `self.service.authorizer = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser.authentication.fetcherAuthorizer()` but that didn't make any difference. Can you please tell where I might be going wrong?

Comment: It is very difficult to say given so little context.  I was able to do it in Objective C, and it looks like you are using Swift? (which shouldn't matter).  At least in Objective C, fetcherAuthorizer is a member variable, not a function call, so maybe that's the issue?  Of course, I'd expect that to give you a compiler error, so maybe that's not it either - I'm just grasping at straws.

Answer (score 0):

In the GIDSignIn Delegate method "didSignIn for" just add

```
let authorizer = user.authentication.fetcherAuthorizer()
self.service.authorizer = authorizer
```

(Swift 4)